# Azure lists no containers but returns information on a given name

Tags: azure, azure-cli

We create container instances and can see them in the correct resource group. However they are not listed

with `az container list --resource-group XXX`. It always returns `[]`

The command `az container show --resource-group XXX --name YYY` returns values.

I don't have any idea what to do to retrieve this (here: YYY) in the list command.

Comment: Can you try using this Powershell cmdlet to pull the container group details 
`Get-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName "<resourceGroupName>"|select -Property * `

Answer (score 1):

***I got the same error when I tried in my environment as below:***

[image]

***Cause:*** *If there are ***no container instances*** allocated under a specific "resource group", an empty list [] is returned*. *Then, in* `Azure` *Portal, I created a new container instance and executed the same command.*

[image]

***It worked for me successfully as shown here:***

```bash
az container list --resource-group "xxxxxxxxRG"
```

[image]